# Multi level radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to create a two-level radio button only for one particular option.
Here I have written a logic that will display an extra two radio buttons under the 'Spring' option. But when it got selected it is rendering for all the options. Alignment is also is not happening as expected.
[image]

HTML

```
<mat-radio-group class = "radio-group"[(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
 <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
    <mat-radio-group class = "radio-group" *ngIf="favoriteSeason ==='Spring'">
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of climate" [value]="season">
      {{season}}
       </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Typescript

```
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];
  climate:string[]=['rainy','hot'];
}
```

I want to create like this.

[image: I want to achieve like this image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more check in if condition

```
*ngIf="season ==='Spring' && favoriteSeason ==='Spring'"
```

For icon aligning issue add below css

Add class="custom-radio-button" for your mat-radio-button element

```
:host ::ng-deep .custom-radio-button .mat-radio-label{
  align-items: start;
}
```

And for selection issue mentioned in below comment you have to customize css with CSS selectors for mat-radio-button to achieve your requirement. Sample code as below:

```
::ng-deep.custom-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked  >label >div > .mat-radio-outer-circle {
       border-color:blue!important; /*outer ring color change*/
  }
   ::ng-deep.custom-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked  >label >div > .mat-radio-inner-circle {
       background-color:blue!important; /*outer ring color change*/
  }

::ng-deep.custom-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle{
   background-color:#fff!important; 
}

::ng-deep.custom-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-outer-circle{
   border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.54)
}
::ng-deep.custom-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle
{
   border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.54)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but still, there are two problems
1. Alignment has shown in the image is messing up. The button is displaying to the vertical region center.
2. Unable to select the option under spring because by default all are being selected as soon as spring option is choosed

Comment: It requires custom css as suggested by @Himanshup7857. For better design you can try mat-tree with radio button

Comment: please see the 2nd problem in my above comment

Comment: Try this 
`:host ::ng-deep .example-radio-button .mat-radio-label{
  align-items: start;
}`

Comment: This has fixed the alignment issue. Still, the selection is not possible as all are under spring is selected as soon as I select the spring radio button

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem by using CSS in your component css file  by using nthchild property. In nth child give that  u want to show this only in your 2nd child.

Comment: but the problem is with the icon alignment which is not happening

Comment: Keep the inner radio buttons inside a div  and  give that div container left margin and try I think it will work in alignment

Comment: That will customize the position of the inner radio button region. But the problem is with outer radio button icon. When the 'Spring' option is selected the radio button icon is becoming vertically center to the child's radio button region as shown in the first image.